# hcatUtil not found when Configuring HP Vertica for HCatalog

Tags: hadoop, hive, vertica, hcatalog

I am trying to configure HP Vertica for HCatalog:
[Configuring HP Vertica for HCatalog](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/HadoopIntegrationGuide/HCatalogConnector/ConfiguringVerticaForHCatalog.htm?Highlight=hcatUtil)

But I can not found hcatUtil on my Vertica cluster. 
Where can I get this utility?

Comment: Just to add, Vertica HCatalog connector do not support Kerberos currently in 7.1 version

Comment: Kerberos is supported in 7.2 (and 7.1 SP2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hcatUtil utility has been introduced in vertica 7.1.1 and is located at /opt/vertica/packages/hcat/tools. If you do not have it there, most likely you're using an older Vertica version.

Answer (score 4):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28743880/922300) said, it's in /opt/vertica/packages/hcat/tools starting with version 7.1.1.  But you probably need some further information:

You need to run hcatUtil on a node in your *Hadoop* cluster; the utility gathers up Hadoop libraries that Vertica also needs to access, so you need to have those libraries available.  Assuming you're not co-locating Vertica nodes on your Hadoop nodes, the easiest way to do this is probably to copy the script to a Hadoop node, run it with output to a temporary directory, and then copy the contents of the temporary directory back to the Vertica node.  (Put them in /opt/vertica/packages/hcat/lib.)  Then proceed with installing the HCatalog connector.

See [this section in the Vertica documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/HadoopIntegrationGuide/HCatalogConnector/ConfiguringVerticaForHCatalog.htm) for more details.  (Link is to 7.2.x, but the process has been the same since the tool was introduced.)